# html table column width, fix width at time of page creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table

If there an easy way to fix the width of the html table columns at the time the page is rendered. I DO NOT want to specify the pixel or percent width of the columns in my code. However, once the page is created and the widths determined based on the initial content in the table I do not want the widths to change, even if the size of the cell content changes.

Just so you understand what i'm trying to do, if I have the content of a cell change(from normal to bold for example), say when I hover over the row, the size of the columns will change. This looks quite odd.

Comment: One of the reasons you shouldn't make a text bold on hover :-) What do you expect the wider text to do? Overflow?

Comment: sure. if i can set it to do that that works. because it wont. there is plenty of room in the cell, it's just that each cell has different amounts of text so when the text becomes bold it changes the ratios of the size needed for each cell so the size changes by a couple of pixels... I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I didn't understand the answer you gave to my comment, but I'll attempt at an answer anyway :-)

What you maybe need is to wrap the content of each cell in a `div` (or some other block element) and set it's width. That should limit the widening of the cells, however as I hinted at im my comment, the wider content will overflow, which most like look ugly. However you didn't really specify what you want the wider content to do...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #the-table td .wrap {
       overflow: hidden; /* try different values for different effects */
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#the-table th, #the-table td').wrapInner(function() {
           return $("<div/>").css("width", $(this).width() + "px");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vx5Zq/

Notice how the letter F is cut off on hover.

Comment: First off, i'll try to clarify on my response to your question. All I'm saying is that when the text is NOT bold, there is plenty of space between the edge of the text and the edge of the cell, so I would think that the text could become BOLD and hence get larger, without overflowing the cell. Sorry, my response before was proly not very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it defiantly it the sorta thing I am looking for. Take a look at my modification: http://jsfiddle.net/Vx5Zq/1/ Notice how in this case the text does not overflow. This is what I was saying when the text would not overflow because there is plenty of room in the cells. Hopefully the example will be worth 1000 words :-P

Comment: So I wont keep you in suspense, It works perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick (not checked though):

```
var w = $('#myTable td.leftCol').outerWidth();
$('#myTable td.leftCol').css({width: w+'px'});
```

[EDIT]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $("table td").each(
                    function() {
                        var w = $(this).outerWidth();
                        alert(w+'px');
                        w *= 2;
                        $(this).css({width: w+'px'});
                        alert(w+'px');
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>def</td>
            <td>ghi</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That won't help much. Widths on a table cell are basicly treated like `min-width`.

Comment: well is there a max width i can set?

Comment: ya, but even as a min width its not working. The table has a set size, so if I set the min-width of each cell, and they add up to the size of the table, they size of the cells can't change. So this should work, no? I think i just need to do something with .each() to make sure i get each element?

Comment: OK, maybe it doesn't. I think I know what issue you mean... Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to solve it, I think using a custom grid instead of tables would be an easier solution x_x

Comment: likely would be easier, but i couldn't find a jquery grid that supported inline form edit. ie. click a row, and the row expands into a form.

Comment: Roll your own. it's just a couple of lines of CSS. Maybe this will help: http://www.1kbgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

Adding some width to your current tds will stop the resizing when the the text goes bold.

First set your table using css to fixed rendering:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mytable{ table-layout: fixed; }
</style>
```

Then you can use jquery to add 2px of width to your tds like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#mytable td').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this) // cache this td
            // set style to 2px wider
            $this.css({ width: $this.outerWidth() + 2, height: $this.outerHeight() + 2 });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a little confused, why am I adding two px of width? I'm trying to stop the cells from changing size. And the css you have does not stop the cells from changing size either

Comment: The extra 2px cement the cell and stop it from expanding when the element goes bold.